# How to disable a button when changing the checkboxes in a table in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I have a table with some images and check boxes. I tried to enable a submit button on changing the any checkbox in the table. My table is like following,

```
<form action="/slideShowPage" method="GET">
    <table id="imgTable" class="table">
        {{#images}}
             <tr>
                 <td><a href="/deleteImage?imageID={{imgURL}}" class="btn btn-danger" title="Clear All">Remove</a><label value={{imgURL}}>{{imgURL}}</label></td>
                 <td><img src={{imgURL}} style="width:100px;height:100px"></td>
                 <td><input id={{imgURL}} type="checkbox" name="image" value={{imgURL}}/><br></td>
             </tr>
         {{/images}}
     </table>
     <br>
     {{#msg}}
         <div class="alert alert-info">{{msg}}</div>
     {{/msg}}

     <a href="/" class="btn btn-success pull-right" title="Add More">Add more</a>
     <input type="submit" value="Create Slide Show" class="btn btn-success pull-left" disabled/>
</form>
```

I tried to enable the button using the javascript below,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
            submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");
    checkboxes.click(function () {
        submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
    });
</script>
```

I got this javascript from [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BPhZe/2014/). But it' not working. Also I'm using NodeJS and my jquery version is `jquery-2.0.3`. Can anyone help me to fix this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log("Cheeeee 1");
        var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
                submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");

        checkboxes.change(function() {
            console.log("Cheeeee");
            submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Because the page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Set the element's disabled property to false

submitButt.disabled = false;
If you're using jQuery, the equivalent would be:

$("input[type='submit']").prop('disabled', false);

or
give id or class to input element like "inputDisabled".
 $('.inputDisabled').removeAttr("disabled");

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Bind to the change event instead of click event.

```
var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");

checkboxes.change(function() {
    submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
});
```

Comment: can you explain more on whats not working. at least is it firing the chage function?

Comment: not working means, there's nothing happens. when I'm selecting a checkbox, I wanted to enable the button. It's not happening..

Comment: can you check whether checkboxes.change function firing or not.

Comment: It's not logging anything.. Is there any other way to do this via Node